# Unable to complete POST request with spoonacular api (add to meal plan)

Tags: python, post, request

I am quite new to REST API work and need help completing this post request. I have been able to pull off GET requests, but I am having trouble here.

Here's the link to the docs for this command: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Add-to-Meal-Plan

And here is my code:

```
    date = "1597897582"
    slot = "1"
    position = "0"
    type = "RECIPE"
    value = {
        "id": 664288,
        "servings": 2,
        "title": "Vanilla Bean Melting Moment Cookies With Caramel Filling",
        "imageType": "jpg"
    }

    url = f'https://api.spoonacular.com/mealplanner/{USERNAME}/items'

    data = {
        'username': USERNAME,
        'hash': USER_HASH,
        'date': date,
        'slot': slot,
        'type': type,
        'value': value
    }

    requests.post(url, data)
```

To my understanding, this should add the Vanilla Bean dessert to my meal plan's breakfast on the date:  Thursday, August 20, 2020. However, nothing changes to my meal plan and the request call doesn't return anything, so I have nothing to go off of.

Let me know if I need to provide more information, both USER_HASH and USERNAME are strings

Comment: What is your response code?

Comment: 401, so I think an authentication error

Answer (score 0):

Spoonacular docs (provided in link above) says `Content-Type` to be `application/json`.

When body is sent using `data` parameter, `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You have to pass the body dict in `json` parameter instead of `data`.

```
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, I definitely wasn't aware of that; however, I made the change you suggested and there has been no effect. It also wouldn't explain how I am able to make the code work below:



`rand_dict = {
        'apiKey': SECRET_KEY,
        'limitLicense': True,
        'tags': 'dessert',
        'number': 1
    }

    rand_url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random'

    rand_rec = requests.get(rand_url, params=rand_dict)
`

Sorry about that readability, it is for the endpoint: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Random-Recipes

Comment: I tried out this random recipes request with a valid API key, it was successful with valid data and response. May be verify your API key, because you are getting 401 response (Unauthorized)